# How to catch str exception?

Tags: python, exception, string

```
import sys
try:
    raise "xxx"
except str,e:
    print "1",e
except:
    print "2",sys.exc_type,sys.exc_value
```

In the above code a string exception is raised which though deprecated but still a 3rd party library I use uses it.
So how can I catch such exception without relying on catch all, which could be bad.

except str,e: doesn't catch it? why?

system:
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jul 31 2008, 17:28:52) 
[GCC 4.2.3 (Ubuntu 4.2.3-2ubuntu7)] on linux2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution from [python mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_frm/thread/6f82aa367e86a54e/6891821d373b50a8#6891821d373b50a8), not very elegant but will work if can't avoid the need for such hack

```
import sys
try:
     raise "a string exception"
except:
     e, t, tb = sys.exc_info()
     if not isinstance(e, str):
          raise    
     print "caught", e
```

Answer (score 6):

The generic `except:` clause is the only way to catch all str exceptions.

str exceptions are a legacy Python feature. In new code you should use `raise Exception("xxx")` or raise your own Exception subclass, or `assert 0, "xxx"`.

Comment: but what can you do about third part library?

Comment: Find a better 3rd-party library.  OR.  Fix it.  You have the source.  You can change the source.  Just fix it.

Comment: @S.Lott replying after 3 years, why would I waste a day or more fixing  and testing a third party lib and then test it too, when I can fix the issue in less than a hour and I see no problem in doing this atleast for small test projects

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    raise "xxx"

except "xxx":
    print "xxx caught"
```

`except <class>` only works with classes that are a subclass of `Exception` i think. Oh btw, use `basestring` when checking the type of strings, works with unicode strings too.

Comment: i can't catch "xxx" because I don't know what the exception from 3rd party lib will be in real code

Answer (score 2):

Raising raw strings is just wrong. It's a deprecated feature (and as such should have raised warnings). Catching the explicit string will work if you really need it, and so will catching everything. Since catching everything puts the ugliness in *your* code, I recommend catching the string explicitly, or even better: fixing the broken library.

```
try:
    #code_that_throws_string()
    raise("spam")
except "spam":
    pass
```

The pass statement will be reached. There are loads of good reasons not to use strings as exceptions, and this is one of them (the other being: I don't believe you can get tracebacks, so they're largely useless for bug fixing).

So, fix the library (good). Or catch the string explicitly (bad). Or catch everything (very bad) and do some isinstance(e, str) checking (even worse).